# X-editable: How to get id of each row so I can update individual members?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, x-editable

Here are the relevant parts of my code. I am using a mysql query to fetch all the info and displaying it in a table. Currently the table displays information of all users which is editable. I want to make it so it displays just the userID, username,..., and than have a button which I can click which will take me to a page where I can update all that individual users information. Each row will have a button that can be clicked

```
<td data-th="ID">'.$fetch['userID'].'</td>
<td class="userInfo" data-th="Username"id="'.$fetch['userID'].'"key="username">'.$fetch['username'].'</td>
<td class="userInfo" data-th="End" id="'.$fetch['userID'].'" key="end_date">'.$fetch['end_date'].'</td>
```

Each row will have this button. I want to be able to click it and have it take me to another page where it lists the individual users info so it can be updated. I am unsure of how to get this done. How can I pass the userID of the row of the user I want to update?

```
<td> <a href="updatemember.php" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">Link</a> </td>
```

javascript

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $('.userInfo').editable();
        $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function() {
            var col = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
            var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
            var y = $('.input-sm').val();
            var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().text(y);

            $.ajax( {
                url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+'&col='+col,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(s){
                    if(s == 'status') {
                        $(z).html(y);
                    }
                    if(s == 'error') {
                        alert('Error.');
                    }
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert('Error.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Code to update each row

```
$col=$_GET['col'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_GET['data'];

$pbr = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `loginInfo` l
                     INNER JOIN `memberInfo` AS m
                     ON l.userID = m.UserID
                     SET $col = '$data'
                     WHERE m.userID = ?");
$pbr->bind_param("i", $id);
$pbr->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to store id of current record in your  tag id. In your php code when you output your table: `echo "<a href='...' id='$id' .....>"` And in your **jQuery** you can get it by `id = $(this).attr("id")` in onClick handler.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused. So to my button I should add this `<td> <a href="updatemember.php" id = '$id' class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" role="button">Link</a> </td>` and than should I make a new click handler or can I just use my current one thats in the first post?        `$(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");` Sorry for my confusion I haven't dealt with javascript much.